# Can I remove the default root in a Rails application without creating a new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-routing

When creating a new Rails application, by default it serves a "Welcome to Rails" page at `/` unless you specify an alternative `root` in `routes.rb`.

My application currently only serves things from a subpath (e.g. `/api/v1/`) so accessing `/` should result in a 404. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: For example, `root to: 'home#no_root'`, which will render a 404

Comment: That seems to work; is there not a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Applications usually have a root :)

Comment: Fair point. I guess I just need to find something logical. Perhaps a 302 to `/api/v1`.

Comment: It may be best to actually have an entry point, maybe static. For public-facing APIs this may be a good place for a link to the documentation, so anyone who stumples upon your API by accident might consider using it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to render a `404` response, there are two approaches that I can think of.

Firstly, you could route to Rack, and return a simple `404` response:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: proc { [404, {}, ["Not found."]] }
```

Secondly, you could take the obvious route and point root to a controller action that returns `404`:

```
# config/routes.rb
root to: "application#not_found"

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def not_found
  render plain: "Not found.", status: 404
end
```

The third option is, of course, to route to a non-existing action, but I don't think this is a good idea, since the intention is obscured, and could easily be taken for a mistake.

Comment: The [`:text` option was removed from render in Rails 5.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/79a5ea9eadb4d43b62afacedc0706cbe88c54496).  The `:plain` option can be used instead.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @cschroed. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you remove it, you will see the default greeting from Rails, which includes some technical information about your environment. Unlikely this is the behavior you need.

I solved it this way:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    ...
  end

  # To prevent users from seeing the default welcome message "Welcome aboard" from Rails
  root to: redirect('admin/sign_in')
end
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, rails will render 404 default page(not welcome page) in production.